# Pulling data from sharepoint site analytics

Tags: database, sharepoint, graph, data-analysis, sharepoint-online

I am looking to pull site usage data from sharepoint such as daily users, click through rate, which parts of the site they are using the most, which links they are using the most, which documents are being opening the most. Is there a way to do this through excel, any programs, etc. I have been looking at Power BI, Excel, Power Query, etc. I haven't found a way to pull the data from sharepoint analytics itself though.
I am looking to pull data from the sharepoint site and display it as a chart, a Pareto chart for example.

Answer (score 0):

1.The current situation that the site usage analysis page can export:
Site owners can export the 90-days site usage data in an excel file by going to the download button in the upper right corner on site usage page. Report on unique viewers, site visits, popular platforms and site traffic. For popular content on the site (news posts, documents and pages) the report will be for last 7 days.
[excel_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQVpI.png)

2.I've also tried getting data from the web in Excel, but it doesn't work. There is currently only one connector between site usage and PowerBI.

I tracked down a published post in [UserVoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/): [Export to Excel on Site usage](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/088bb622-de1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8914). You can vote and comment anytime.

3.You might try using the Office 365 Admin API to use, retrieve and store the data in a database, and then report on it with PowerBI. This requires registering with Azure AD and give it permissions to the API.
Reference: [Office 365 Management Activity API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)

Comment: Hi, Is there any progress on this thread?